# Shopify - Using product type in static section block, unable to display value

Tags: shopify

I have a static section with blocks that allow the merchant to choose from a list of products. I have the blocks working in the dashboard as expected, but I can't figure out how to display the values of each of the products.

This is what my schema looks like:

```
{
  "name": "New Arrivals",
  "max_blocks": 4,
  "blocks": [
    {
      "type": "new-arrival",
      "name": "New Arrival",
      "settings": [
        {
          "type": "product",
          "id": "product",
          "label": "Product"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here's a simplified version of my for loop:

```
{% if section.blocks.size > 0 %}
        {% for block in section.blocks %}
            <!-- Individual product values here -->
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```

Normally, in order to retrieve block content I'd use something like this:

```
{{ block.settings.product.title }}
```

But there must be a different way of getting the product information when using the product type like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:
`{%- assign product = all_products[block.settings.product] -%}`

That will grab your product from the block. Then use `product` as needed for other properties like `title` and `price`. Eg: `{{ product.title }}`

Comment: I finally got through to technical support and this is the same solution they provided. Thank you. I'm wondering though, what is the hyphen doing on the opening and closing percentage signs?

Comment: Nevermind, I stumbled across the answer here https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/basics/whitespace